# how I can delete empty lines and lines starting from '/publications'?

Tags: python, line

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
request = requests.get("https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqRggKIkBDQklTS2pvUVkyOTJhV1JmZEdWNGRGOXhkV1Z5ZVlJQkZRb0lMMjB2TURKcU56RVNDUzl0THpBeFkzQjVlU2dBUAE/sections/CAQqSggAKkYICiJAQ0JJU0tqb1FZMjkyYVdSZmRHVjRkRjl4ZFdWeWVZSUJGUW9JTDIwdk1ESnFOekVTQ1M5dEx6QXhZM0I1ZVNnQVAB?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen")
content = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')  
find = content.find('div', class_='ajwQHc BL5WZb')
#open('test.html', 'w').write(findstr.find)
h3 = find.find_all('h3')
time = find.find_all('time')
link = find.find_all('article')#.find_all('a').get('href').replace('.', '')
result = []
#print('https://news.google.com' + link)
for result in link:
    alinks = result.find_all('a')
    alinks1 = []
    for alinks1 in alinks:
        alinks2 = alinks1.get('href')
        alinksreplace = str(alinks2)
        alinksreplace1 = alinksreplace.replace(".", "")
        alinksreplace2 = alinksreplace1.replace("None", "")
        print(alinksreplace2)[![enter image description here]
```

I want remove empty lines and links started with /publications:

I tried a lot of ways but nothing works

```
/articles/CBMinQFodHRwczovL3d3dy5rcHZpLmNvbS9uZXdzL25hdGlvbmFsX25ld3MvZGFpbHktd3lvbWluZy1jb3JvbmF2aXJ1cy11cGRhdGUtNDA0LW5ldy1jYXNlcy0xLTAxNi1uZXctcmVjb3Zlcmllcy9hcnRpY2xlX2JlZmMxN2MyLTI1NGYtNTQxOS1hOGIwLTIyYmUwNjNlY2NhYi5odG1s0gEA?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
/publications/CAAqBwgKMInn9gowidnVAg?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen
```

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, data, errors, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text. Also show desired output.

Comment: Heyo! welcome to stack overflow. Stack overflow is a "teach a man to fish" type of place. As a result, it focuses on high quality questions, as much as high quality answers. This is often a discouraging truth for new users; You post a question, and suddenly your downvoted and you have a bunch of angry comments. I recommend reading through this to get an idea of what a good question on stack overflow looks like. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question may get taken down, but that's OK! Just about everyone posts a few bad questions when they're getting started.

Comment: how are lines separated? by `\n`?

Comment: how I can separator sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to go over here. Let's go over your misconceptions first

```
result = []
for result in link:
    #...
```

and

```
    alinks1 = []
    for alinks1 in alinks:
        #...
```

You keep instantiating variables before your for loop unnecessarily and incorrectly. Neither `alinks1` or `result` will be a list unless the returns from the RSE (right side expression) are a list. It would be better to assume you have no idea what will be returned and just accept it for whatever it is.

---

```
        alinks2 = alinks1.get('href')
        alinksreplace = str(alinks2)
        alinksreplace1 = alinksreplace.replace(".", "")
        alinksreplace2 = alinksreplace1.replace("None", "")
```

This could get ridiculous and cumbersome very quickly. If you need to do this much formatting to the data you should be using regex.

---

Below is a heavily reformatted version of your code that examples what you want to do. The main portion is not trivial.

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

REP = re.compile(r'None|\n|publications/|\.') #content to remove

req = requests.get("https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqRggKIkBDQklTS2pvUVkyOTJhV1JmZEdWNGRGOXhkV1Z5ZVlJQkZRb0lMMjB2TURKcU56RVNDUzl0THpBeFkzQjVlU2dBUAE/sections/CAQqSggAKkYICiJAQ0JJU0tqb1FZMjkyYVdSZmRHVjRkRjl4ZFdWeWVZSUJGUW9JTDIwdk1ESnFOekVTQ1M5dEx6QXhZM0I1ZVNnQVAB?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen")

if find := BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser').find('div', class_='ajwQHc BL5WZb'):
    links = list(filter(lambda a: bool(a), [REP.sub('', str(link.get('href'))) for result in find.find_all('article') for link in result.find_all('a')]))
    print(*links, sep='\n')
else:
    print('No content was found.')
```

The main thing to note is this part of the main line:

`list(filter(lambda a: bool(a), [REP.sub('', str(link.get('href')))`

Start from right to left to understand it. First we get the link, but convert it to a string (no matter what) in order to catch `None`. Then the value is processed through the replacement `regex`. We then dump the results into a `filter` so we can skip all occurrences of `''`, and finally convert it to a `list`, which may or may not be actually necessary ... it depends on your skill and needs.

Comment: Sorry, but how I can save output to file, coz when I trying to do it it mess up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241936/discussion-between-michael-guidry-and-timur-yun).